# how to fix the error watcher doesn't exist on type in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js. I have declared a function in methods called `watcher()` and I want to call this function when page load at first, so I called this function in mounted like `mounted(){this.watcher()}`.  It's not showing any error in browser's console. The website is also working fine but in command line, while rendering it says the watcher does not exist on type:

```js
export default {
  name: 'Products',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  firestore() {},
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {},
    addNewProduct() {},
    watcher() {
      db.collection('products').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        this.products = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const product = {
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            price: doc.data().price
          }
          this.products.push(product);
        });
      });
    },
    CancelUpdateProduct() {},
    updateProduct(product) {},
    productEdit(product) {},
    showEditModal() {},
    reset() {},
    deleteProduct(id) {},
    addProduct() {}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$watcher();
  }
}
```

I just want to remove this error in comand line, as it may make any error in future!

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the error in the console?

Comment: it's not showing any error in console but in the command line

Comment: how can i share the screenshot here ?

Comment: okay i have shared the image as well so you can see the clear image of the error

Comment: yes, I mean command line, you can edit your question, or upload it to a website like Imgur and put the link in the comments.

Comment: yes bro i have done that i would love to get the clear answer of my question which can make me feel better

Comment: could you please tell me is your syntax(closed paranthesis for methods ) correct?

Comment: with your `mounted` method, did you mean `mounted` hook? if so, it's in the wrong place, it should not be in `methods: {}`, it should be in the same level as `data` and `methods`

Comment: -PALLAMOLLA SAI yes the closed syntax is correct i have checked that's why website is running with no error but in the command line there is error

Comment: it is in the same level as data

Comment: @KamalAlhomsi Please don't suggest **images** of screenshots.  When adding errors or things with text content, the **actual textual content** needs to be pasted, as text, in the question.

Comment: You're calling `this.$watcher()` in your `mounted` hook but your method has no dollar-sign prefix (nor should it). You want `this.watcher()`

Comment: i changed this this.$watcher to this.watcher but still not working